# An error should occur, but no error occurred and completed

Tags: rxjs

I'm rxjs newbie~
I'm studying rxjs... I intentionally tried to occur an error.
However, no error message was output and "complete!!" was output.
Why...?
(I write and run this code at fiddle)

```js
// 4, 8, 1, 14, A, 7

const { of } = rxjs;
const { tap, filter } = rxjs.operators;

const obs$ = of(4, 8, 1, 14, 'A', 7);
const subscriber = {
    next: x => console.log(x),
    error: err => console.log('error:', err),
    complete: console.log('complete!!')
}

obs$
    .pipe(
        filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
    )
    .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Image that I want.
[image]

Result of my code 
[image]

Comment: Why did you expect an error? `'A' % 2` evaluates to NaN, which doesn't equal 1, so the value is filtered out, and that's it. No error thrown.

Comment: @mbojko Ooooh..... Oh I thought `'A' % 2` occur error... But I thought wrong.. Thanks Teacher!!!!!

Comment: @mbojko  I want to choice your comment!!!!!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yeah its like `Number("A")%2==0` always false because `Number('A')` will be [Not-A-Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'A' % 2` doesn't throw an error. It returns NaN. `NaN === 0` returns false. So 'A' doesn't pass your filter.

This observable completing is the expected behavior in this case.

Try this:

```ts
const obs$ = of(4, 8, 1, 14, 'A', 7);
const subscriber = {
    next: x => console.log(x),
    error: err => console.log('error:', err),
    complete: console.log('complete!!')
}

obs$.pipe(

  tap(x => {
    if(isNaN(x % 2)) throw "This is an error";
  }),
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0)

).subscribe(subscriber);
```